# What does "href" stand for?

Tags: html, w3c, web-standards

After writing html for couple of years I realized that I don't really know why the `href` attribute is named *"href"* .

The [HTML Recomendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-href) does not shed light on the subject by saying :

> This attribute specifies the location of a Web resource, thus defining a link between the current element (the source anchor) and the destination anchor defined by this attribute.

Also the [HTML 4.01 DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#inline) does not provide a lot of clue .

> href        %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for linked resource --

I could make an educated guess for the meaning , but i was hoping for something canonical .

Comment: ...and how do you pronounce it? `eych-ref`? `harref`? `hurrf`? Perhaps the r is silent and it's just `heffff`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It stands for Hypertext Reference

From the [source](http://www.w3.org/Provider/ServerWriter.html) written by Tim Berners-Lee himself.:

> "Help" is all that is displayed, with some indication that it is an
>   option. If the user choses (clicks a mouse on, choses by number
>   depending on which client he has) then the client asks the server for
>   /HEPDATA/HELP. ("A" is for "anchor", **"HREF" is for "hypertext
>   reference"**)

Answer (score 5):

Hypertext REFerence.  You can see the link here for more about it -

http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/44472/href

Answer (score 3):

Hypertext Reference, From a day where links used to be called "hyperlinks" hypertext is simply link to another big of information, and hypertext reference is the link itself:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext

Answer (score 1):

Its stand for Hypertext Reference .

The href attribute specifies the URL of the page the link goes to.

If the href attribute is not present, the  tag is not a hyperlink.

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking for. He's asking what the full form of `href` is.

Answer (score 0):

href stands for Hypertext REFerence. It is the attribute of the html which gives the URL of the page the link goes to ....

Further information can be obtained from

http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt   - By Tim Berners Lee
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp
http://tomayko.com/writings/wtf-is-an-href-anyway